# How to disable Gmail auto label

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have a **self-defined** label A. Some emails are labeled with A automaticaly. I did found a filter that matches the email. But the related action is labeling it with B. And that is the only one matching the email.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places that filter can appear. The first is under the filters section. The second place is under the section where you configure Gmail to pull in mail from other accounts. All email pulled in from account X can be automatically labeled.

To check/change this:

1. go to Gear/settings/
2. Click the Accounts and Import tab
3. Look in the Check mail from other accounts (using POP3) section.
4. Click on the "edit info" link.

You can:

- Leave a copy of retrieved message on the server.
- Label incoming messages:
- Archive incoming messages (Skip the Inbox).

Comment: It's not because I label the pulled in mail from other accounts.But you remind me! I find the mail labeled with A automaticly is  forwarded by my another email. I check my filters and find a filter that label all emails from another account with A. Thx!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, had done this a while ago and had forgotten how to undo it

Answer (score 0):

Letting my fingers browse the web, and found out that the best workaround for this is to delete labels that are not in use.

Here's how:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/qLUXFBJfW6c%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: Not exactly my situation. The label A is defined by me, and I did use it for some emails. But some other emails are auto labeled with A without any related filter.